# How do you split a string inside a list?

Tags: python-3.x, split

I got this type of strings inside a list :

```
[['AAAA-BBBBBBB-10.00.00.0', 'AAAAAAAA', '00:00:00:00:00:00', '000', 'BBBBBBB', 'AAAAA:00'], [
```

when i export this list to csv the strings inside the commas (,) are in different cells but `'AAAA-BBBBBBB-10.00.00.0'` is all in one cell. I wanted it to look like this:

```
[['AAAA-BBBBBBB','10.00.00.0', 'AAAAAAAA', '00:00:00:00:00:00', '000', 'BBBBBBB', 'AAAAA:00'], [
```

so when i export it to csv file the strings `'AAAA-BBBBBBB','10.00.00.0'` will be in 2 different cells.
I tried:

```
dp1 = [d.replace("-1"," 1").split() for d in data]
```

but it doesnt work it seems its ignoring it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate the elements of the outer list, change the composition of the 1st item of the inner list and assing it back to your outer list:

```
data = [['AAAA-BBBBBBB-10.00.00.0', 'AAAAAAAA', '00:00:00:00:00:00', 
         '000', 'BBBBBBB', 'AAAAA:00'],
        []] 

for idx, d in enumerate(data):
    if d:
        orig = d[0].replace("-1"," 1").split()  # create a 2 part list
        d = orig + d[1:]                        # use list slicing
    data[idx] = d                               # assign it back to your big list

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[['AAAA-BBBBBBB', '10.00.00.0', 'AAAAAAAA', '00:00:00:00:00:00', 
  '000', 'BBBBBBB', 'AAAAA:00'], 
 []]
```